# How to plot chi-squared chart in jupyter notebook with df=5 and alpha=0.05?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

How to plot chi-squared plot in jupyter notebook?

It is a two-tailed, with alpha = 0.05 and df = 5

I just want to plot it and show critical areas

Comment: Questions about how to use software are against community guidelines. [help/on-topic]

Answer (score 0):

Use [`.interval`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.interval.html#scipy.stats.rv_continuous.interval) method to get confidence intervals

```
In [1]: import scipy.stats as ss

In [2]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

In [3]: import numpy as np

# Distrubution object, chisqure with df=5
In [4]: dist = ss.chi2(5)

# Two tail C.I.
In [5]: dist.interval(0.95)
Out[5]: (0.831211613486663, 12.832501994030027)

In [7]: plt.plot(np.linspace(0,20), dist.pdf(np.linspace(0,20)))
Out[7]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x1a0e9fe048>]

In [10]: plt.vlines(dist.interval(0.95), ymin=0, ymax=plt.ylim()[1])
Out[10]: <matplotlib.collections.LineCollection at 0x1a16df7940>

In [11]: plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I have changed the last part like this, to plot my calculated data in between
​plt.vlines(dist.interval(0.95), ymin=0, ymax=plt.ylim()[1],colors='red')
plt.vlines(3.6654,ymin=0, ymax=plt.ylim()[1],colors='green')

How can I put a legend for this plot to say reds are critical and green is calculated value?